# Android Emulator Never starts

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, haxm

I'm trying starting emulator though Android SDK, I've installed Intel HAXM prperly , the emulator window shows up but it never starts!

I'm getting this:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'MyAVD' emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1024MB emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 48MB emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 256MB Hax is enabled Hax ram_size 0x40000000 HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode. emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86_64 emulation: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 POPCNT Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly! console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555 VCPU shutdown request EAX=80000001 EBX=01b81000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000 ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fcf000 EBP=00100000 ESP=00547084 EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0 ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA] SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl GDT= 000000000053b020 00000030 IDT= 0000000000000000 00000000 CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fc9000 CR4=00000020 DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400 EFER=0000000000000500 VCPU shutdown request EAX=80000001 EBX=01b81000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000 ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fcf000 EBP=00100000 ESP=00547084 EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0 ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA] SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl GDT= 000000000053b020 00000030 IDT= 0000000000000000 00000000 CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fc9000 CR4=00000020 DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400 EFER=0000000000000500 VCPU shutdown request EAX=80000001 EBX=01b81000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000 ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fcf000 EBP=00100000 ESP=00547084 EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0 ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA] SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl GDT= 000000000053b020 00000030 IDT= 0000000000000000 00000000 CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fc9000 CR4=00000020 DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400 EFER=0000000000000500 VCPU shutdown request EAX=80000001 EBX=01b81000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000 ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fcf000 EBP=00100000 ESP=00547084 EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0 ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA] SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl GDT= 000000000053b020 00000030 IDT= 0000000000000000 00000000 CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fc9000 CR4=00000020 DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400 EFER=0000000000000500 VCPU shutdown request EAX=80000001 EBX=01b81000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000 ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fcf000 EBP=00100000 ESP=00547084 EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0 ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA] SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl GDT= 000000000053b020 00000030 IDT= 0000000000000000 00000000 CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fc9000 CR4=00000020 DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400 EFER=0000000000000500 VCPU shutdown request EAX=80000001 EBX=01b81000 ECX=c0000080 EDX=00000000 ESI=00013c80 EDI=01fcf000 EBP=00100000 ESP=00547084 EIP=001000fa EFL=00000046 [---Z-P-] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0 ES =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] CS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA] SS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] DS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] FS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] GS =0018 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS [-WA] LDT=0000 00000000 00000000 00008200 DPL=0 LDT TR =0020 00000000 00000fff 00808900 DPL=0 TSS64-avl GDT= 000000000053b020 00000030 IDT= 0000000000000000 00000000 CR0=80000011 CR2=0000000000000000 CR3=0000000001fc9000 CR4=00000020 DR0=0000000000000000 DR1=0000000000000000 DR2=0000000000000000 DR3=0000000000000000 DR6=00000000ffff0ff0 DR7=0000000000000400 EFER=0000000000000500
```

[Emulator Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJuh3.png)

[Emulator Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gKZ5.png)

I'm just using the SDK without any Eclipse or Android Studio. This is for testing Ionic Apps.

Comment: To how much? I have 4GB RAM. So 1GB is ok? And what amount for Heap?

Comment: Oops! Didn't worked!

Comment: I'm Creating Nexus S

Comment: Could not load func glCheckFramebufferStatus
Could not load func glDeleteFramebuffers
Could not load func glIsRenderbuffer
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
Could not load func glBindRenderbuffer
Could not load func glDeleteRenderbuffers
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
Could not load func glGenRenderbuffers
Could not load func glRenderbufferStorage
Could not load func glGetRenderbufferParameteriv
Could not load func glFramebufferRenderbuffer
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
VCPU shutdown request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I just want to test my ionic apps, whether any emulator or something else. So the best way I found out to use Ionic Lab and run application through CLI commands. Well the Genymotion Emulator worked for me but it was crashing a lot so I decided to go for Ionic Lab. Thanks for the support.